# Normalizing values depending on group in R

Tags: r, range, max, min, normalize

I have this dataset:

```
> head(meltCalcium)
  Time    Cell Intensity
1    1 IntDen1  306852.5
2    2 IntDen1  302892.2
3    3 IntDen1  298258.6
4    4 IntDen1  300769.9
5    5 IntDen1  301971.8
6    6 IntDen1  302585.6

> tail(meltCalcium)
      Time     Cell Intensity
32531  659 IntDen49  47788.16
32532  660 IntDen49  47560.32
32533  661 IntDen49  47738.24
32534  662 IntDen49  48968.96
32535  663 IntDen49  48796.16
32536  664 IntDen49  48156.80
```

I have 49 Cells and the time reaches 664 for each one of them. In this case time is not important, as I'd like to get the normalized Intensity for each cell (so (Intensity - min)/(max - min)), and possibly adding it as a new column to the dataframe.

I tried

`> meltCalcium$normalized <- with(meltCalcium, (Intensity - min(Intensity))/diff(range(Intensity)))`

but in this way the max and the min are calculated using the Intensity over all Cells. How can I do it for each cell separately?

Thanks!

Comment: See also: [R function for normalization based on one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64873299/10488504)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the formula by group :

```
library(dplyr)
result <- meltCalcium %>%
           group_by(Cell) %>%
           mutate(normalized = (Intensity-min(Intensity))/diff(range(Intensity)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
normalise_vec_min_max <- function(num_vec){
  minnv <- min(num_vec, na.rm = TRUE)
  maxnv <- max(num_vec, na.rm = TRUE)
  return((num_vec - minnv) / (maxnv - minnv))
}

with(meltCalcium, ave(Intensity, Cell, FUN = normalise_vec_min_max))
```

Data:

```
meltCalcium <- structure(list(Time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 
662L, 663L, 664L), Cell = c("IntDen1", "IntDen1", "IntDen1", 
"IntDen1", "IntDen1", "IntDen1", "IntDen49", "IntDen49", "IntDen49", 
"IntDen49", "IntDen49", "IntDen49"), Intensity = c(306852.5, 
302892.2, 298258.6, 300769.9, 301971.8, 302585.6, 47788.16, 47560.32, 
47738.24, 48968.96, 48796.16, 48156.8)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```